# error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand, I've seen solutions but I can't relate them to my query

Tags: c, string, pointers, function-pointers

I can easily remove this error by replacing`&(name+0)` by `&name[0]` or just `name`, but why I'm getting this error??

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void print(char *c)
{
   while(*c != '\0')
   {
       printf("%c",*c);
       c++;
   } 
   printf("\n");
}
int main(void)
{
    char name[]="Hello World!";
    print(&(name+0)); //ERROR here
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: name+0 is an expression, like 2+2. You can't take the address of 2+2, only the address of a variable. (&name)+0 would be OK.

Comment: Try `print(name);`

Comment: It'll do the work but I'm asking why I'm getting this error for this particular case??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of

```
print(&(name+0)); //ERROR here
```

seems to be a result of some misunderstanding.

First things first - why is it a syntactic error?

`(name + 0)` does not evaluate to an *lvalue*. Hence, you cannot take the address of the value of that expression.

A simple way to decide whether something is an *lvalue* or not is to ask yourself: Can I use it on the LHS of an assignment operator? In your case, you have to ask: Can I use

```
(name + 0) = <something>;
```

The answer is "no".

If you want to pass the address of the first element of `name` to `print`, you can use couple of methods.

```
print(&(name[0]));  // Explicitly get the first element's address.
print(name);        // The array decays to the address of the first element.
```

Answer (score 1):

To quote the C11 standard in section 6.3.2.1 subsection 1:

> An lvalue is an expression (with an object type other than void) that
>   potentially designates an object; if an lvalue does not designate an
>   object when it is evaluated, the behavior is undefined. When an object
>   is said to have a particular type, the type is specified by the lvalue
>   used to designate the object.

In this case, you've got the expression `(name + 0)`.  While `name` itself designates an object and is therefore an lvalue, the result of the addition in that expression does not designate an object, but rather a value, and is not an lvalue and thus ineligible for the unary `&` operator.

Answer (score 0):

The `&(name+0)` is not equivalent to `&name[0]`. `&name[0]` is the same as `&(*(name + 0))`. Note the **indirection**, when you are using the subscript operator it's the same as offsetting the pointer **and dereferencing** it.